# elasticsearch exact match containing hash value

Tags: indexing, elasticsearch, document

I am facing problem with elastic search, i am using query to search data from document. following is the query to search single data from document.

```
"query": {
      "filtered": {
     "query": {
         "query_string": {
            "query": "'.$lotnumber.'",
            "fields": ["LotNumber"]
                           }
                      }
            }
     }
   }'
```

It is working fine for simple value but if $lotnumber contains any value with hash in between then it is showing all the data from document.any one here who can help me to resolve problem of searching exact value from document with hash value ??

Comment: So what you are saying is that if `$lotNumber` has a value of `lot12#34` then its returning the entire document? Or returning more results?

Comment: Nate thanks for reply. yes exactly what is happening. i am using query  to search from indexing but it is returning all the data instead of one.

Answer (score 0):

The first things that I would think of in this case is make the field lotnumber not-analyzed in your mapping. That should do the trick.

In your mapping

```
"album": {
  "type": "string",
  "fields": {
    "raw": {
      "type": "string",
      "index": "not_analyzed"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Jettro, do you have any demonstration regarding creating field as not-analyzed ??

Comment: I changed the answer and added the sample